# How to write MySQL syntax correctly, if WHERE clause contains binded parameters, and binded parameters can be either NULL or have some value?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to write MySQL syntax correctly, if WHERE clause contains bound parameters, and bound parameters can be either NULL or have some value?

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tabel
WHERE name = :name AND
family = :family AND
midname = :midname";
```

It works only if bound parameters aren't NULL. Should I write separate statements in case parameters are NULL?

Comment: You need two Statements. because you can not check `= null`. The check is `is null`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to write a seperate statement for that, seeing that checking for NULL in MySQL is done using `IS NULL` and not using `= NULL`

Next to that, PDO prepared statements considers every parameter to be data, and `IS NULL` or `NULL` itself is MySQL value, and not data